Unable to find/use bjam in linux ec2
I cant run/find bjam after boost install.
I have correctly installed boost and able to compile some examples from there using gcc, however I want to compile the example ssl boost server program. It seems to require extra includes from openssl. AWS ec2 already has openssl. I even tried to install openssl source as well.
Ideally I would like to be able to run the Jamfiles for the examples using bjam. I've tried so many things after googling get bjam working. After building boost isnt bjam supposed to work or be there somewhere?
Any help appreciated...
Downloaded/installed boost. Able to compile SOME programs with g++ -I /home/ec2-user. Tried downloading bjam files. Not sure how to install after extract

If you extract the archive, say to folder ./boost/ running
./bootstrap.sh

in that folder will give you ./boost/b2
This will work to build the examples. E.g.:
docker run --rm -i -t ubuntu
apt update
set -o vi
apt-get -yy install build-essential wget libssl-dev
wget https://archives.boost.io/release/1.86.0/source/boost_1_86_0.tar.bz2
tar xf boost_1_86_0.tar.bz2 
cd boost_1_86_0/
./bootstrap.sh 
cd libs/asio/example/cpp11/ssl/
../../../../../b2

This successfully builds the cpp11/ssl examples from scratch on a fresh ubuntu server installation.
UPDATE Amazon Linux
Amazon Linux 2 seems to be EOL, and yum doesn't work in a amazonlinux:2 container. Just using the latest version (AL2023) instead:
docker run --rm -it amazonlinux

Then the following minimal steps successfully build the relevant examples:
yum install -y make g++ wget tar bzip2 openssl openssl-devel

# download and extract boost
wget https://archives.boost.io/release/1.86.0/source/boost_1_86_0.tar.bz2
tar xf boost_1_86_0.tar.bz2 

# build b2
cd boost_1_86_0/
./bootstrap.sh 

# link into path
mkdir -pv ~/bin
ln -sfv "$PWD/b2" ~/bin/
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"

# build asio/beast ssl examples
(cd libs/beast/example/http/server/async-ssl/ && b2)
(cd libs/asio/example/cpp11/ssl/ && b2)

Test them with
bin.v2/libs/asio/example/cpp11/ssl/gcc-11/debug/x86_64/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/server
bin.v2/libs/beast/example/http/server/async-ssl/gcc-11/debug/x86_64/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/http-server-async-ssl


You can even build without b2:
cd /boost_1_86_0/libs/asio/example/cpp11/ssl/
g++ -I/boost_1_86_0/ server.cpp -lssl -lcrypto
./a.out

Or
cd /boost_1_86_0/libs/beast/example/http/server/async-ssl/
g++ -I/boost_1_86_0/{,libs/beast} http_server_async_ssl.cpp -lssl -lcrypto
./a.out 


Thanks. Found this useful even though I have aws ec2 not ubuntu. eg used   sudo yum install openssl-devel   (it says already have it though). I used your  ./bootstrap.sh
asio example
good output and with http-server-async with good output...  however  http-server-async-ssl still failed with output
...failed updating 5 targets...
gcc.link ../../../../../bin.v2/libs/beast/example/http/server/async-ssl/gcc-7/debug/x86_64/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/http-server-async-ssl
etc etc

Aws ec2 does have ubuntu. It only depends on what AMI you use. You didn't tell me what AMI, so I picked a popular one. If you tell me what you're using, I can try. My gut tells me the required SSL libraries aren't found.

yeah, thats what was thinking.. but I couldnt find them after searching.. in the end I might have to go with ubuntu. Im using the standard Amazon 2  AMI

I've updated my answer with the exact steps to repro using Amazon Linux, both with b2 or just manually using g++. I still think you were missing ssl stuff (yum install openssl-devel)

Thanks for all your hard work.   I stil get the errors   ...patience...
...found 1813 targets...
...updating 2 targets...
gcc.compile.c++ ../../../../../../bin.v2/libs/beast/example/http/server/async-ssl/gcc-7/debug/x86_64/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
/http_server_async_ssl.o
gcc.link ../../../../../../bin.v2/libs/beast/example/http/server/async-ssl/gcc-7/debug/x86_64/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/http-s
erver-async-ssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

"g++"    -o "../../../../../../bin.v2/libs/beast/example/http/server/async-ssl/gcc-7/debug/x86_64/threading-multi/visibility-hidde
n/http-server-async-ssl" -Wl,--start-group "../../../../../../bin.v2/libs/beast/example/http/server/async-ssl/gcc-7/debug/x86_64/threa
ding-multi/visibility-hidden/http_server_async_ssl.o" "../../../../../../bin.v2/libs/beast/gcc-7/debug/x86_64/link-static/threading-mu
lti/visibility-hidden/lib-asio-ssl.a" "../../../../../../bin.v2/libs/beast/gcc-7/debug/x86_64/link-static/threading-multi/visibility-h

..."../../../../../../bin.v2/libs/beast/gcc-7/debug/x86_64/link-static/threading-multi/visibility-h
idden/lib-asio.a" "../../../../../../bin.v2/libs/beast/gcc-7/debug/x86_64/link-static/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/lib-beast.a"
-Wl,-Bstatic -ldl -Wl,-Bdynamic -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group -fPIC -m64 -pthread -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hi
dden
...failed gcc.link ../../../../../../bin.v2/libs/beast/example/http/server/async-ssl/gcc-7/debug/x86_64/threading-multi/visibility-hid
den/http-server-async-ssl...

sudo yum install -y make g++ wget tar bzip2 openssl openssl-devel   shows everything "already installed" including ssl and "nothing to do"

Wait what. "cannot find -ldl" means your system is broken full stop. How are you on gcc-7 by the way? That's pretty old. Perhaps check ldconfig, reinstall the core packages or something. Are you perhaps using a non-standard toolchain?

I have decided just to start from scratch with Ubuntu. Thanks very much for the help. It will get me running the new system easily...
